# Automatic MYSQL failover

Tags: mysql, replication, clustering, high-availability, failover

We have a wordpress environment however this is not a wordpress question. Our scenario is that front Ends connect to a MYSQL backend (MYSQL VM1) which is replicated to a backup vm (MYSQL VM2). The replication is Master - Master.

What we're looking for is a MYSQL HA cluster with automatic failover where if VM1 dies / is unresponsive, connection fails over to VM2. Anything you'd recommend ?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Galera for HA.  Master-Master, especially if you write to both masters, has a lot of problems.  Read other Questions on this topic.